# Add bbappend conditional task without overriding recipe function

Tags: yocto, overriding

For the given example:

**Existing recipe:**
[some-yocto-upstream-thing_1.0.bb]

```
do_configure_prepend () {
    <necessary logic>
}

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

I'm creating a bbappend to this recipe which needs to have a function I wrote be called before the do_configure_prepend gets called.  But I only want this function called for the class-target and not for class-native build.

I can create a do_configure_prepend_class-target, but that overrides the recipe version (during class-target builds).  But then the existing needed logic won't be run.

I can create a custom task to be called before do_configure_prepend (via addtask) but this is then called for class-native, too (unwanted).

Any ideas?  I'd prefer to avoid just overriding an earlier built-in task (do_patch, etc.) since the upstream recipe could eventually define one and I'd be breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

No, using

```
do_configure_prepend_class-target () {
    <necessary logic>
}
```

should work. For `class-target`, `do_configure` will be prepended by your code.

One example of such a prepend with override is in [OE-Core/go.inc](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/go/go.inc).

Comment: But then the existing yocto do_configure_prepend will not be called since I'm replacing it with do_configure_prepend_class-target during target build.  That prevents the "<necessary logic>" from running.  To be clear, the "<necessary logic>" is present in the yocto recipe.  The function I'm introducing includes additional logic that I need to have executed.  Your example kind-of confuses things, in that regard.

Comment: No, you can have multiple `_prepend` in a recipe, they'll all apply.

Comment: You would get your issues if you did it the other way around: `do_configure_class-target_prepend`. That would cancel out any non `_class-target` values.